# How to access Session from outside Controllers Asp .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have declared a Session `Session["DbName"]` at my account controller and now I wanna access it from the services. I can access it only inside other controllers but I couldn't find a way to access it from other files.

I tryed using global variables but when a user logs in he changes the variable for all the other users who are currently logged in. I need to find a way to make it so when other users join they dont change eachothers `DbName` but I have no ideas.

Any help or idea would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code where are you trying to access session pls?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework (MVC5) or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @RichardDeeming I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: @Shatsuki `HttpContext.Current.Session` should work. I like to inject it as a scoped service via the Microsoft DI container.